# Two models share the same table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I have two or more Model that will be using the same table. Lets say **RecordCareerWorkshop** and **RecordRecruitment**. I do this because they might have different validation requirement, display name, validation error message, etc.

I create two models, and put a [Table("record")] on top of the class.

For example:

```
[Table("records")]
public class RecordCareerWorkshop
```

and

```
[Table("records")]
public class RecordRecruitment
```

However, when I run the webpage, I get the error message as follow:

> The entity types 'RecordCareerWorkshop' and 'RecordRecruitment' cannot
>   share table 'Record' because they are not in the same type hierarchy
>   or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with
>   matching primary keys between them.

May I know how can I use the two models sharing the same table ?

Edited:

If I derived the both models from same base class for table **records**, eg:

```
public class Record
```

and

```
public class RecordCareerWorkShop : Record
```

and

```
public class RecordRecruitment : Record
```

I will get the error message:

> Unknown column 'Extent1.Discriminator' in 'field list'

whenever I execute any code, for example:

```
var records = db.RecordRecruitment.Where(x => x.company_id == id).ToList();
```

Really have no idea where Extent1,Discriminator pop up.

Comment: This sounds more like the ORM than MVC itself... but I can fully understand why the ORM might be confused by your intent there

Answer (score 1):

You can go either one of two routes here:

- Derive both models from the same base-class.
- Include just one entity and then create two ViewModels that will be fed from the main entity.

In case both entities are related, you should probably go for option 1.
If they are just different representations of the same underlying concept, you should go for option 2.

Comment: HI Kenneth, do you mind to give me example of (1) ? Please check my edited question.